# what happened if a all-column-same row already exist when run a 'replace into' sql?

Tags: mysql, replace

We know a 'replace' will delete the primary-column-same row, and then insert the new row, if the primary column is the same with a current exist row.

For example, id is primary of t:
create table t (`id` int(10), `num` int(10), primary key (`id`));
Now I run 'replace into t(id, num) values(1, 123);' twice.

At second time I run this sql, mysql will "foolishly" delete and insert back again this row? Or, mysql will clever enough do nothing?

/////////updated as belows

mysql> replace t values(1,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)------

mysql> replace t values(1,4); 
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)-------

mysql> replace t values(1,4); 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)------

When I first time replace (1,4), it said 2 rows affected; second time it said 1 rows affectd. 
We know at first time, it delete (1,3) and insert (1,4); But at second time, what happened at mysql server? 
delete (1,4) and insert (1,4) again? Or, do nothing?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem. It's a problem with laziness of OP not just trying it.

Comment: @Bohemian Maybe I have not described clearly.
mysql> replace t values(1,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)------
mysql> replace t values(1,4);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)-------
mysql> replace t values(1,4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)------
first time replace (1,4), it said 2 rows affected; second time it said 1 rows affectd. 
first time, it delete (1,3) and insert (1,4); second time, what happened at mysql server?
delete (1,4) and insert (1,4) again? Or, do nothing?